# What does it mean that condition?

Tags: c

What should this `current -> yes` evaluate in if condition? (It's not complete code you can assume any question in yes)

```
typedef struct node {
    char *question;
    struct node *no;
    struct node *yes;
} node;

node *current;

if (current->yes) {
    current = current->yes;
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: `if (current->yes) current = current->yes;` means "if there is another question when the user answers 'yes', then update `current` to point to that question"

Comment: Is this a question about the `->` token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code :

```
if (current->yes) {
    current = current->yes;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (current->yes != NULL) {
    current = current->yes;
}
```

So the condition is checking yes to not be NULL pointer

Comment: Not just similar, equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

This means if `current->yes` not `0` (not null pointer).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the address of `yes` member of type `struct node *`, by dereferencing   `current` object. Which is, if allocated the memory properly, it'll be non zero, and if not it'll be 0 or `NULL`. For example memory allocations can fail.

So, basically the condition: `if (current->yes) { ... }` checks whether memory is allocated properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `if()` construct in C is defined to evaluate its argument and compare it to `0`. As such, `if(foo)` is always equivalent to `if(foo != 0)` or `if(foo != NULL)`, considering that `NULL` compares equal to `0`.

Or, put another way, `if(myPointer)` checks whether the pointer points to a valid object. This is a very common idiom in C programming.

---

This is true even if you write `if(a == b)`. This is fully equivalent to `if((a == b) != 0)`: The value of `a == b` is either `0` for false or `1` for true, and that result is then compared to `0` by the abstract machine to determine which branch to execute. Obviously, compilers will directly use the result of the comparison in `if(a == b)`, because that's equivalent to producing the `1` or `0` and then comparing a second time to `0`. However, the language is defined with the extra comparison against `0` to make it fully agnostic about what kind of expression is used within the parentheses. All the language cares about is that the resulting value is comparable to `0`.

Comment: Detail: "The if() construct in C is defined to evaluate its argument, and compare it to NULL if the value is a pointer, or to 0 for all other types." --> C has _The if statement_: ".. the expression compares unequal to 0." without any type consideration somehow involving `NULL`.  Net effect is [mox nix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mox_nix).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right. I was trying to be overly precise, with the result of being less precise... :-( I have removed most of the talk about `NULL` now and only left one mention of it to clarify what `if(pointer)` does.